# Calculate x when n = x^x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible when you know some `n` calculate the `x` if

$$n = x^x$$

?

Sorry, I did't even know how this equation is called, any help appreciate.

Comment: and what is $n$ supposed to be ?

Comment: Lambert W function is helpful.

Comment: `n` can be any number as input, the output need to be `x`

Comment: just use newton method

Comment: @lion sry, what is the newton method?

Comment: google Newton–Raphson method

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54210/is-xx-y-solvable-for-x, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532336/how-to-solve-equations-of-this-form-xx-n – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24y%20%3D%20x%5Ex%24%2C%20solve&p=1)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, of the mentioned post by @MartinR Thanks, I'll look into it!

Comment: Check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_2

Comment: Thanks guys, you are awesome :)

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27392/whats-the-deal-with-lambert-w-function-questions lol

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
n= x^x \\
x \ln x =e^{\ln x} \ln x = \ln n \\
\ln x =W(\ln n) \\
x=e^{W(\ln n)}
\end{eqnarray*}
Where $W$ is the Lambert function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Absurd. This is wrong question