# How to go about solving $x=2^{\frac1x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would you go about solving an equation like this, and what values of x did you end up with.

$$x=2^{\frac 1x}$$

Also, how would you generalise for

$$x=n^{\frac1x}$$

These come from

$$\sqrt[{\sqrt[{\sqrt[\cdots]n}]n}]n$$
$$x=\sqrt[{\sqrt[{\sqrt[\cdots]n}]n}]n$$
$$x=\sqrt[x]n$$
$$x=n^{\frac1x}$$

Comment: We know that $1^1 < 2$ and $2^2 > 2$ so $1<x<2$. Now, $1^1=1$ and $1<1.5^{1.5} < 2$ so $1.5<x<2$. Now, $1.75^{1.75}>2$ so $1.5<x<1.75$. See what I am doing here? Continuing in the same fashion, I get that $1.5<x<1.625$ and so on. This is certainly not the best way of solving for $x$, however, but it is an approach. [This related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532336/how-to-solve-equations-of-this-form-xx-n?rq=1) might serve useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve equations of this form: $x^x = n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532336/how-to-solve-equations-of-this-form-xx-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of 
$$x=n^{\frac1x}$$ is given by
$$x=\frac{\log (n)}{W(\log (n))}$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

If you do not want to use it, you could consider that you look for the zero of 
$$f(x)=x-n^{\frac1x}$$ or, much better
$$g(x)=\log(x)-\frac 1x \log(n)$$ or even better
$$h(x)=x\log(x)- \log(n)$$

Consider the last one and compute derivatives
$$h'(x)=\log (x)+1 \qquad \text{and }\qquad  h''(x)=\frac1x$$ So, the derivative cancels at $x_*=\frac 1e$; for this value $h(x_*)=-\frac{e \log (n)+1}{e}$ and $h''(x_*) >0$. So, $x_*$ is a minimum. To get an estimate, develop as a Taylor series around $x_*$
$$h(x)=-\left(\log (n)+\frac{1}{e}\right)+\frac{1}{2} e
   \left(x-\frac{1}{e}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{e}\right)^3\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, solve for the positive root and get,as an estimate,
$$x_0=\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{e \log (n)+1}+1}{e}$$ Now, start using Newton method.

Comment: How do you get from f(x) to g(x) and h(x)? I feel like i am missing something simple here.

Comment: From $f$ to $g$ : write $x=n^{1/x}$ and take logarithms and subtract. From $g$ to $h$, just multiply by $x$

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$x=2^{\frac1x}\iff x^x=2$$

abd since $f(x)=x^x$ is strictly increasing (for $x>1/e$), with $f(x)\le1$ for $0<x\le 1$, $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=4$ by IVT an unique solution exists which can be found by numerical methods.