# How to find what number raised to its own power is equal to a given number?

Tags: logarithms, tetration

If $x^x = 3$, how can I find x?
I know I can rearrange this to $\log_x(3) = x$, and that some calculators can solve this, but how would you do this manually?

Comment: Do you know about the Lambert W function? Do you know how to get $x = e^{W(\log(3))}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532336/how-to-solve-equations-of-this-form-xx-n

Comment: Subtract the equation by $3$ to obtain $x^x-3 = 0$ and then use Newton's Method to approximate the root.

Comment: Draw graph of $ y= x^x $ and $ y=3 $ the intersection point is the solution for the given equation.

Answer (score 2):

First, we have $x \ln x = \ln 3$. Here, $\ln x$ represents the natural logarithm. So $$e^{\ln }\ln = \ln 3.$$ Therefore,
\begin{align}
\ln x &= W( \ln 3 ) \\\implies x &= e^{W( \ln 3)}
\end{align}

Comment: I looked up the Lambert W function, but I don't really get how this helps.  What is W?

Comment: @Phenomniverse you can search on YouTube and watch some videos.